# FirebaseAuthException with code = "account-exists-with-different-credential" does not have email as Firebase Auth docs suggest

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app that uses Firebase auth.  My users can sign in with Facebook, Gmail, and email/password. [Email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) is **not** enabled on this project.

I am running into a problem in the following scenario:

- The user creates an account with an email/password and signs out.
- The user signs in with Facebook.
- FirebaseAuthException is thrown with code = "account-exists-with-different-credential" but with email = null.  In the past, the email in the FirebaseAuthException was never null.  Without the email, I will not be able to call "fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)" as suggested in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors)

Anyone knows what is going on.  Here is my signInWithFacebook function

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final loginResult = await facebookAuth.login();

    switch (loginResult.status) {
      case LoginStatus.success:
        final accessToken = loginResult.accessToken!;

        // Here is where the FirebaseAuthException is thrown because 
        // email/password exists for the same email.
        return auth.signInWithCredential(
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token),
        );

      case LoginStatus.cancelled:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAILED',
          message: loginResult.message,
        );
      case LoginStatus.failed:
      case LoginStatus.operationInProgress:
        throw UnimplementedError('Login Status is not implemented yet.');
    }
  }
```

This is the code that catches the exception:

```
try {
  await signInWithFacebook();
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
  if (error.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
    // error.email is null, It was not the case in the past.
    await FirebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(error.email!);
  }
}
```

This is how my pubspec.yaml look like:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'
  flutter: 3.13.9

dependencies:
  android_id: ^0.3.6
  audio_waveforms: ^1.0.4
  badges: ^3.1.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.3
  cloud_functions: ^4.4.2
  connectivity_plus: ^5.0.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.0
  dotted_border: ^2.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.5.1
  firebase_app_check: ^0.2.0+1
  firebase_auth: ^4.10.1
  firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.7
  firebase_database: ^10.2.7
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.9
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.2.7
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.8
  firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.5.12
  flash: ^3.0.5+1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^6.0.2
  flutter_hooks: ^0.20.3
  flutter_image_compress: ^2.0.4
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^16.1.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  geocoding: ^2.1.1
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  go_router: ^11.1.4
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.5
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.4.3
  http: ^1.1.0
  image_cropper: ^5.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.9
  intl: ^0.18.0
  just_audio: ^0.9.35
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.5.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^6.0.7296
  open_mail_app: ^0.4.5
  package_info_plus: ^4.2.0
  path: ^1.8.3
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  purchases_flutter: ^4.13.0
  rate_my_app: ^2.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.3.8
  share_plus: ^7.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  showcaseview: ^2.0.3
  stack_trace: ^1.11.0
  store_redirect: ^2.0.1
  swipe_to: ^1.0.2
  timeago: ^3.5.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.14
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter
  mocktail: ^1.0.1
  very_good_analysis: ^5.1.0
```

Comment: *firebaser here* Hey Aimn. I've asked our engineering team to help with troubleshooting here. The first question from that is whether you have [enabled account linking](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) in the Firebase console? If you've selected "Create multiple accounts for each identity provider" there, the API will **not** return the email address.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have "Link accounts that use the same email" selected.  I just checked right now.  I also made sure to follow instructions to disable "Email enumeration protection" since I don't like its approach of linking account.  Also, I am 100% my code was working 100% before introducing "email enumeration protection.".

Comment: I have a same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I was waiting for a fix from the Firebase team.!!

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, any update from the Firebase team on this issue.?

Comment: When I answered around email enumeration protection, OP said that their project was created over a year ago - so it can't be related to that change. That left me without a clue what could be going on.